# PHP DomDocument behaving differently in CLI and Web Browser

Tags: domdocument, php

I 'm using the following code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<i><p><strong>From: fsong | #001</strong><br/>I hate you DomDocument :(.</p></i><br/>you'd be surprised<br/>");
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Running it in the CLI gets me

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<i><p><strong>From: fsong | #001</strong><br>I hate you DomDocument :(.</p></i><br>you'd be surprised<br>
</body></html>
```

while running it through the web browser returns:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : i in Entity, line: 1 in /home/xx/www/test/topic_archiver_test.php on line 50
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
<html><body> 
<i></i><p><strong>From: fsong | #001</strong><br>I hate you DomDocument :(.</p> 
<br>you'd be surprised<br> 
</body></html>
```

Now I realize nesting a (p) tag inside an (i) tag breaks HTML rules, but I'm not the one responsible for the HTML. For some reason the CLI mode returns the document like the original while the web page version closes the (i) tag early to keep the HTML well-formed.

Is there something in my php.ini configurations that is causing the difference in behaviours? I checked the official docs (http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.configuration.php) and there doesn't seem to be any configuration files or settings for DomDocument.

Comment: does the "dom" section of your `phpinfo()` yield the same results for cli and cgi?

Comment: ^ Nope they both show the same settings.

Comment: Insert an `echo phpversion(), '-', LIBXML_VERSION;` to validate your PHP versions are the same.

Comment: Thanks; it turns out that I am running different versions of php. Running the above code in CLI mode gets me `5.2.14-20632` while web page mode gets me `5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7-20706`

Now the question becomes how I can get the same behavior in the web page mode...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like for some reason it is trying to validate the HTML. I'm not getting any errors running php 5.3.5 and libxml 2.7.6.

One way to ignore the warning is prepending a '@' character, of course this is kind of a hack.

```
@$dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: It looks like I'm using the same libxml as you are, but my php version is php 5.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You could try turning off [strictErrorChecking](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.stricterrorchecking) from [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)